# Same setup different hash rate

Tags: litecoin, mining-hardware, hashpower, mining-setup, scrypt

I have one computer with windows 8.1 13.11 driver and a 280x which gets 720KHS and another computer with the same setup which gets 620KHS.

They have a different cpu ram and psu (both have quality ones).

How can this be?

Answer (score 1):

> I have one computer with windows 8.1 13.11 driver and a 280x which
>   gets 720KHS and another computer with the same setup which gets
>   620KHS.
>
> They have a different cpu ram and psu (both have quality ones).
>
> How can this be?

It's because they have a different ram. With scrypt mining RAM is of up most importance. The faster/higher quality the ram, the faster you can mine.

Scrypt was made to require ram so it would slow down the over all hashing power and to resist asics.

Comment: as far as I know, Cgminer uses the gpu ram. and  i had on that computer win7 and it mined at 707 KHS but i had no temps or fan speed and could not overclock.

Comment: So I have Reinstalled the 13.12 driver and not I am at 718KHS which is good enough :)